# How to find out the reason a line is highlighted when using elpy?

Tags: emacs, flymake

When a line of mine is unacceptable to the default syntax/quality checker used with [elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy), it underlines the line in red.

How do I find out why the lne is underlined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd have to hover over the line with your mouse.

However that's very un-emacs-y so I'd suggest using [flymake-cursor](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeCursor) so that the message appears in the mini buffer instead.

Comment: For some reason, on Ubuntu Emacs24, when I hover over the line, nothing happens. Furthermore when I [download flymake-cursor.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/flymake-cursor.el) and `eval-buffer` I get nothing when I navigate the cursor to be on top squiggly red lines it creates.

Comment: make sure `flymake-cursor-mode` is enabled. I personnally don't use autoloads and use a `(require 'flymake-cursor)` in my configuration